# Using Python on Visual Studio Code, get a just in time debugger error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running my Python code in Visual Studio Code and I get this error;

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in [4372] python.exe. Just-In-Time debugging this
> exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-in-time
> debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from
> Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-time.

How do I fix this? There is no Tools menu in VS Code where this can be fixed like in other versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Your mixing up Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code.  You need to look for a guide about setting up a Python dev env using VS Code.

Comment: This is Visual Studio Code. I am very clear about that. I have run Python on it before, but now I am getting this error.

Comment: where did you install this Python interpreter from and how? What version of Python is it? Does this happen for any Python program? How exactly are you running the program(s)?

Comment: @arame3333 And do you have any third-party Python extensions installed in VSC?

Comment: how exactly are you running the Python program? There are multiple ways to launch a Python program in VS Code, which one are you using?

Answer (score -2):

The error you are encountering is related to Just-In-Time (JIT) debugging.

To resolve this issue:

**Disable Just-In-Time Debugging:**
Modify the Visual Studio setting by adding `"python.disableJITAutoAttach": true`

And also ensure that you are having a latest version of python extension.

Comment: where is this setting from?... what extension? Or did you make it up? or did... something _**else**_  make it up for you?

Comment: Just-In-Time (JIT) debugging setting is available in full version of Visual Studio. I didn't mention any particular extension any popular or highly regarded extension is enough

Comment: @ThirumalaikumarM But the question is specifically about VSC, not Visual Studio.

Comment: and Visual Studio does not do its settings in JSON. It can _export_ to a vsconfig, but this does not look like a typical naming format for Visual Studio config settings.